# Add xml-stylesheet and get standalone = yes

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I added the solution to the code below.

The code at the bottom is what I have. I removed the creation of all tags.

At the top in the xml file I get.`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` Note that standalone is no, even thou I have it set to yes.

The first question: How do I get standalone = yes?

I would like to add `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my.stylesheet.xsl"?>` at line two in the xml file.

Second question: How do I do that?

Some useful links? Anything?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();  
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
ProcessingInstruction pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"my.stylesheet.xsl\"");

Element root = doc.createElement("root-element");
doc.appendChild(root);
doc.insertBefore(pi, root);    

<cut>  

TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transfac.setAttribute("indent-number", new Integer(2));
Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "name");

FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
BufferedOutputStream bout= new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(bout, "utf-8")));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added

```
doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
ProcessingInstruction pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"my.stylesheet.xsl\"");`
```

before the cut and

```
doc.insertBefore(pi, root);
```

right after the root element was appended to the doc.

Answer (score 3):

in my code, I wrote :

---

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.newDocument();
document.setXmlStandalone(true);
```

---

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
```

---

output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`